# Join two table in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have two tables like below.

```
Product TABLE

id name count
1  book 3
2  shoes 4
3  pen 3
```

```
Category TABLE

id category_id product_id
1    4           1
2    5           1
3    1           2
4    3           3
```

I want to get the result, when i query like `... where product.id = 1`.

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "book",
  "count" : 3,
  "categories" : [
      4,
      5
    ],
}
```

The following codes are showing models and their relationship.

Product in model

```
class Product extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
        'count',
    ];

    public function categories()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Category::class);
    }
}
```

Controller

```
 ...
 $product = Product::with('categories')->get();
 ...
```

But result is like this.

```
{
  "id" : 1,
  "name" : "book",
  "count" : 3,
  "categories" : [
      {
         "category_id": 4
      },
      {
         "category_id": 5
      }
    ],
}
```

I think i should use the relationship between two tables.

Comment: So you just want the categories to be an array of ids rather than an array of objects?

Comment: Yes, right. I want to get the result of only category Ids array.

Answer (score 0):

try something like

```
$product = Product::with((array('categories'=>function($query){
    $query->pluck('category_id');
}))->get();
```

Another option

`Product::with('categories:id,category_id')->get();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use like this

```
$products = Product::with('categories')->get();
$products->transform(function ($item) {
    $item->categories = $item->categories->pluck('category_id')->all();
});
```